# How to search in MarkLogic JSON for a key's value at a particular path in the file?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, search, marklogic

I have a few JSON documents of a particular format in my database. There is a key that occurs at two places in the document. I want to write a search query where I can search for the value at only the 2nd occurrence. For a clearer picture please refer to the below sample created.

I tried `cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery("c1",cts.trueQuery())` but it is not path specified. I also tried `cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery("c1", "e/c1")`.

```
 {
    "a": "aa",
    "b": "bb",
    "c": {
        "c1": "cc",
        "c2": "ccc"
    },
    "d": "dd",
    "e": {
        "c1": "xx"
    }
}
```

I expect the query to fetch all values of `c1` under `e` from all documents and put them in an array for further processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the path is known, consider defining a path range index on the specific path and using a cts.pathRangeQuery or cts.values, depending on your goal.

For example, define a path range index on /e/c1 (or e/c1 if it needs to be relative), and then use cts.values on that index to fetch all values:

`cts.values(cts.pathReference("e/c1"))`

Similarly, you can use a cts.pathRangeQuery if you want to search for documents containing a specific value, rather than a list of all the values:

`cts.search(cts.pathRangeQuery("e/c1","=","xx"))`

Further details: [Understanding Path Range Indexes](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/range_index#id_40666).

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to retrieve the list of values, you want to set an index. If you wanted all `c1` values, you'd use a range index, but since you only want some of them, you'll need a path range index. After you have that set up, you can use `cts.values`.

Further details: [Using Range Indexes for Value Lexicons](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/range_index#id_90556).

Answer (score 1):

I concur with Dave, if you are looking for values anyhow, use `cts.values` rather than `cts.search`.

The path range query that Kim suggests is good for accurate searching, but the scope query should work too, and has the advantage of not needing pre-defined range indexes. The way to use it is as follows:

```
cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery("e",
  cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery("c1",
    cts.trueQuery()))
```

As explained in the `Usage Notes` of the docs on [`cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery), scope queries do require positions to be enabled. It is recommended to enable both `word position` and `element word position` indexes.

One important difference between above scope queries, and a path index on `e/c1` is that with the path index the `c1` must be a child of `e`, while the scope query only checks for descendants. The scope query is essentially the equivalent of the path `e//c1`.

HTH!